# Filtering DataGridView Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am attempting to create a button which takes 2 user inputs and then filters the datagridview depending on the two inputs. I am using winforms and Sql. Here is some code I found and tried implementing but it doesn't populate the datagridview with the filtered data.

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        dataSet31.Personal_Details.Clear();
        using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter =
new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand2.CommandText = "select * from Personal_Details WHERE '" + comboBox2 + "' LIKE '" + textBox1 + "'",
    "Data Source=Z46308;Initial Catalog=VSTest;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (DataTable dataTable = new DataTable())
            {
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                this.DataGridView01.DataSource = dataTable;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you load data in form load, then you don't need to run a query to filter grid, you can simply use a `DataView` to filter the data table.

Comment: The above approach will scale better   - meaning if the Personal_Details contains 100,000 records it will take a long time to load the DataView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you load data in form load, then you don't need to run a query to filter grid, you can simply use a `DataView` to filter the data table.

In the below sample I suppose that you use comboBox2 to select the column name that you want to filter based on.

```
//Create a data table to store data when you load them in form load
private DataTable dataTable;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataTable = new DataTable();
    string constring = @"Data Source=Z46308;Initial Catalog=VSTest;Integrated Security=True";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Personal_Details", con))
        {
            //Fill the data table here
            sda.Fill(dataTable);
        }
    }
    //Set the data source of grid
    this.DataGridView01.DataSource = new DataView(dataTable);
}
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get the datasource from grid
    var dv = (DataView)this.DataGridView01.DataSource;

    //comboBox2.SelectedItem or comboBox2.SelectedValue based on your settings
    //Apply filter to data source
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("{0} Like '%{1}%'",comboBox2.SelectedItem,   textBox1.Text);
}
```

**EDIT**

You can also use `this.DataGridView01.DataSource = dataTable;` to set data source, and then when filtering simply use `dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = ....`

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. As I am a beginner I would appreciate if you could spare some time to explain what each line does.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you create a new DataView object? You can use DataTable.DefaultView as well, right?

Comment: You are welcome :) I'll add comments to code to make it more useful:)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you yet again :)

Comment: @danish I created it just instead of `BindingSource`, but you are right. While the answers work properly it could be written without creating an instance of DataView.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Just a quick little question, with this code how can I clear the data from the table and reload the original data using another button. I would normally have this:

`private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataSet31.Personal_Details.Clear();
            sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet31);
        }`

Comment: @imamage597  You don't need to reload data and you only need to set the filter to empty or null

Comment: @RezaAghaei I understand that but if I modify the data then the table doesn't update if you understand what I mean. Say if I delete the data and then filter it, it'll still show up until I relaunch the application.

Comment: If you change data, then you need load data to dataTable again and set the dataSource again.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I understand that but how do I clear it first?

Comment: Maybe I can't understand your question correctly, But you should know you don't need to clear the table, you need just to set the filter to empty string. Also to reload data from database, you can simply load data to that dataTable and set the data source again.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I understand I have to load the data but how do I clear the previous data in the table because when I reload the data it just adds data to the old data.

Comment: I'm not sure if you load data using dataAdapter it add records to table, but if you want, you can `dataTable=new DataTable()` and then fill it using `sda.Fill(dataTable);` and then set it as DataSource of grid again `this.DataGridView01.DataSource = new DataView(dataTable);`

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes I know this. I mean that if I do that, it keeps the old data and adds the new data aswell. I want it to clear the old data first before the new data is added to the DataGridView

Comment: I got what you mean, you can `dataTable=new DataTable();` as first line of your the method that you load data, as I did in answer (I edited the answer).

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you. Finally got that one solved haha.

Comment: @imamage597 Happy to hear that you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to run the query on database all the time. Here is an alternate approach.

You can make use of `DataView.RowFilter` property to filter the data in memory. Once you have done this, you can rebind data to your grid. Assuming the data table object name is `table`, this is what you can do in button click.

```
        table.DefaultView.RowFilter = combobox1.SelectedText + " LIKE '%" + textbox1.Text + "%'";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing comboBox2 to comboBox2.SelectedValue and textBox1 to textBox1.Text.
I don't think the query will return any results the way you have it at the moment.

I am using similar thing in my application, have a look at my code and see if you can adjust it to meet your needs:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT o.OrderID AS ID,o.ProductID AS ProductID, p.ProductName AS 'ProductName', s.CompanyName AS Supplier, c.CategoryName AS Category, o.UnitPrice AS 'Unit Price', o.Quantity AS Quantity, (o.UnitPrice * o.Quantity) AS 'Sub-Total'" +
          "FROM [Order Details] o INNER JOIN Products p ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID " +
          "INNER JOIN Suppliers s ON p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID INNER JOIN Categories c ON p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID WHERE OrderID = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'", new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["databaseConnection1"].ConnectionString));
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader sdrEmp = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        if (sdrEmp.HasRows)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(sdrEmp);
            //Response.Write(dt);
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.DataBind();        // BIND DATABASE TABLE WITH THE GRIDVIEW.
        }
    }
```

Comment: I missed that. That's my bad but I still have no results ?

Comment: Bare with me, I am simply a rookie but I have 2 errors. ViewState does not exist in the current context and there is no definition for Databind in Datagridview?

Comment: I think you can remove those two lines:

    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

and 

    dataGridView1.DataBind()
You will also need to add a Connection String in your Web.Config

Comment: This is a windows forms application. There is no concept of ViewState here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //dataSet31.Personal_Details.Clear();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter =
new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText = "select * from vtypes WHERE VoucherType ='" + comboBox1.Text + "' AND VouOrder = '" + textBox1.Text + "'",
    "Data Source=SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB50A0;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (DataTable dataTable = new DataTable())
            {
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
            }
        }
    }
```